# I just instantiated the ViewController, why is its IBOutlet nil？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, iboutlet

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
vc.label.text = "my Label" // Crashes here, label is nil
```

What if I need to use it here?

[vc.lable is nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4kiW.png)

[There's an IBOutlet in the ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlDLO.png)

Comment: How do you know it is nil? Show your real code.

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the correct view controller. A common mistake: two Controllers in Storyboard, both assigned the class `ViewController` ... **one** is given the Identifier "ViewController" ... but then the label is added and the `@IBOutlet` connection is made to the ***other*** `ViewController`.

Comment: I'm sure, because there's only one ViewController in the project

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Code Editor's UILabel @IBOutlet to the UILabel on the Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: This IBOutlet is generated through the connection

Comment: You can try deleting the generated connection and then reconnecting it again using step indicated above.

Comment: I have tried and recreated a project test and it is still like this.